# Ubuntu 20.04 Fresh Installation Freezes

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, nvidia-geforce

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.
Hardware.
Dell Vostro 7950
GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q
CPU Intel i7, 9th Gen
RAM 32G

These no-default changes: 
In step 4, I chose `'Normal installation'`; turn off `'Download updates while installing Ubuntu'`and tick on `'Instal third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi...'` without `'Configure Secure Boot'`

In step 5, I choose to encrypt the disk. 
`Erase disk and install Ubuntu` 
`Advanced features... > Use LVM with new Ubuntu installation` and `Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security`.

After the first login, I do the next things:

1. Super > Software & Updates > Download from: > Other... > Select Best Server> ... > Choose Server
2. Updates

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt dist-upgrade
reboot
```

3. I checked, in Additional Drivers, it is set to `'Use NVIDIA driver meta package from nvidia-driver-440'`

I log in again, open the Terminal. After a few minutes, the system freeze completely. I could open any virtual terminal (`CTRL + ALT + F1`, also tried `CTRL + ALT + FN + F1`).

So, I restarted the system by Magic SysRq sequence (REISUB).

---

Edit output for `lspci` command

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
        DeviceName: Onboard - Video
        Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Where should I look in error logs?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Issues often common across similar models: Dell 7700 pre-installed 18.04, 20.04 works
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2443622
Dell 7791 UEFI update & some settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2431450&page=3
Dell 7390 Performance issues on 7390 April 2020
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ice-Lake-Linux-Thermal-Fix-7390
Ubuntu 19.10 Provides Good Out-Of-The-Box Support For The Dell XPS 7390 Icelake Laptop
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=dell-xps7390-ubuntu1910&num=1

Comment: @pilot6 added the output
thanks for the comment

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the comment. I am going to check links

Comment: fyi, my MSI RTX2060 freezed with `nvidia-driver-440` at fresh install ; I use the `335` and everything (almost) goes fine.

Comment: @B.duGaray thanks for the info :) What does mean "almost"? Any freezes with `335`?

Comment: I do not have any freeze, I just have a backlight laggy hotkeys. I had that in my late laptop, I don't remember how I fixed it. It's not very annoying. But no more freeze ! (Everytime I say I'll write a writeup, everytime I don't)

Comment: Also, I edited my `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` file to (replace / with EOL) : `blacklist nouveau/blacklist lbm-nouveau/alias nouveau off/alias lbm-nouveau off`. I do think I found that in the Arch Wiki for Nvidia but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Maybe stuppid question. Freeze with intel gpu or nvidia?

Comment: @nobody Thank you for the question. Maybe I didn't get what is the question, but let me try to answer. When I use `nvidia-driver-440` or `nvidia-driver-435` it freezes after a few minutes, even when I do not my computer. When I switch to Nouveau drivers it freezes, after an half hour of usage.